# Making a line graph using ggplot2 using dates

Tags: r, date, ggplot2, tidyverse

So I have a list of dates and corresponding data as follows:

```
DATE        Event
7/14/2021   Start
7/14/2021   Start
7/14/2021   Start
7/14/2021   Start
7/13/2021   Start
7/12/2021   Start
7/12/2021   Start
7/12/2021   Start
7/12/2021   Start
7/12/2021   Start
7/12/2021   Start
7/11/2021   Start
7/11/2021   Start
7/6/2021    Submit
6/30/2021   Submit
6/25/2021   Submit
6/24/2021   Submit
6/23/2021   Submit
6/22/2021   Submit
6/22/2021   Submit
```

All I want to do is have 1 plot with two lines:

- x-axis: DATE
- y-axis: count of records
- Line 1: Starts
- Line 2: Submits

I'm trying to do this with ggplot and the tidyverse, any help is welcome!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

** saw your comment, if you want to have separate lines, based on the Event field, use the argument `group` in the function `ggplot()`. You can add color by Event, as well. I've added it to the code.

This should work for you. Look for the inline comment that starts with "# this is the part you're interested in."

```
# original data
df = data.frame(DATE........Event = c("7/14/2021   Start",
                                      "7/14/2021   Start","7/14/2021   Start",
                                      "7/14/2021   Start","7/13/2021   Start",
                                      "7/12/2021   Start","7/12/2021   Start","7/12/2021   Start",
                                      "7/12/2021   Start","7/12/2021   Start",
                                      "7/12/2021   Start","7/11/2021   Start","7/11/2021   Start",
                                      "7/6/2021   Submit","6/30/2021   Submit",
                                      "6/25/2021   Submit","6/24/2021   Submit",
                                      "6/23/2021   Submit","6/22/2021   Submit","6/22/2021   Submit")
)

# had to fix the data, because of the way you posted it
names(df)[1] <- "Date"
df <- separate(df, Date, into = c("Date", "Event"), sep = "   ")

# this is the part you're interested in
# first you need the date to be a date object
# the library lubridate is the best option for simplicity
df <- df %>% mutate(Date = lubridate::mdy(Date))

# then you can graph the count
#               and group by event**
ggplot(df, aes(x = Date, 
               group = Event,
               color = Event)) + 
  geom_line(stat = "count")
```

This is what it looks like:
[image]

Comment: This isn't quite it, I need a line for Starts and a line for Submits, two lines one plot.

Comment: This looks more right, can u update the plot?

Comment: @John Thomas I updated the graph after I had initially updated the code. That was before your comment, though. The graph is aligned with the code.  Maybe you were looking at it while I was changing it?

Comment: FYI @Kat, you can read in the data more easily using `read.table("clipboard", header = TRUE)` on windows (and linux, I think) and `read.table(pipe("pbpaste"), header=TRUE)` on macos (both after highlighting the data text in the question and copying). It'll read this in as a two-column frame without the need for `separate(.)` (though it still needs `mdy` or `as.Date`).